# Compensation Log Records (CLR) in UNDO-Phase of Database Recovery

Tags: recovery, database-theory

The compensation logs' redo-information corresponds to the undo-information of the log entry that made their creation necessary during the undo-phase.

That sounds to me like the CLRs redo information is the same as the undo information of the logs that sparked them.

But should't it be that they have the REDO information in order to cancel out the executed UNDO operations in case of an interrupted recovery process?

**Here's an example:**

let T2 be a looser transaction:

<#55, T2, P3, J=J+9, J = J-9, #53>

*J=J+9 is the redo-op and J = J-9 is the undo-op.*

Now the CLR that's appended to the Log file during the redo-phase would be:

<#56, T2, J=J-9,__, #53>

With J=J-9 being the undo-op of the original log entry as the redo information in the CLR. In case the recovery is interrupted, the log-entry #56 will be executed during redo phase.

The point of CLR is to ensure that restarting the recovery process and running it again always leads to the same result.
How does running the J=J-9 operation during the redo phase of the rerun ensure this?

Can somebody pease explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a change that you need to apply to the database.  You can either make the change and record how to undo it if an transaction aborts, or you can record what you need to do (REDO) and consult the database and redo log to figure out the current state of the database.  See also [http://ariel.its.unimelb.edu.au/~yuan/Ingres/clr.html](http://ariel.its.unimelb.edu.au/%7Eyuan/Ingres/clr.html)